# Can I edit an event (gamepad)'s behavior?

Tags: xorg, games, events

Ok, so I'm attempting to fix my gamepad's (or rather, dance pad's) input, because the d-pad is acting like an axis rather than 4 buttons. 
I attempted to use xboxdrv, to no avail.

So my question is, is there anyway to directly edit an event's behavior? I was thinking of making a script to have the joystick release a button event after it hits a certain threshold. (Was that confusing?)

**Update:** I tried editing 10-evdev.conf (in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d) but it didn't change anything. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Get `evtest` and watch the behavior - you can definitely do this, but you need to know what to react to.

Comment: I know about evtest